# UITableView not refreshing when numberOfRowsInSection = 0

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have a `UITableView` that presents a list of nearby places.  I can filter the table using a `UISegmentedControl` by the type of place (bar, restaurant, etc.)  The issue is that when I attempt to filter the list by a segment that has 0 records, the previous segments records are not being replaced with an empty table.

Every time I click on a different segment, I'm calling `tableView.reloadData()` and feed the table a filtered array containing places of the selected type.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience , The issue lie in the logic that you have made on dynamically change of height of tableView hopefully because only cellForRowAtIndexPath will not called in case of your number of rows are 0.It reload but some logic in cellForRowAtIndex path is there which is never called.